# Can't boot into Windows 7 or Ubuntu12.10 on a dual boot computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wubi

My computer suddenly shut down a few times when I was using Ubuntu and then I couldn't even boot into Windows or Ubuntu. It's a dual boot computer and I installed Ubuntu from Windows with Wubi.

When I tried to boot into Ubuntu it said that

> Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /

I search online and found that the command

> mount -o remount, rw /

I tried it but only sometimes it worked and even then the computer then shut down suddenly...

And when it didn't work. The following message was shown:

> /host: device is busy
>
> /run: device is busy
>
> /dev: device is busy

But I could boot into Ubuntu once and used boot-repair to generate a report.(Now I can't seem to be able to boot into Ubuntu anymore) It's [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6742154/).

When I tried to boot into Windows, it just got stuck at the Windows logo screen. And after a while it suddenly shut down.

So based on the report, what's the problem? Is it possible to fix the problem within Ubuntu if I got lucky again and boot into it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would boot into the recovery mode, and enter a root terminal. From there, run `fsck -A -y -f`, to fix these errors.

Please note, however, this sounds like it could be a more serious hardware issue (I've never heard of a computer powering off from hard drive errors). If that doesn't work, odds are, something's malfunctioning inside your computer. Unless you're using a laptop with a not-so-good battery, I would strongly recommend taking your machine to a computer repair center, and have it professionally diagnosed.

Comment: That mode is not visible on the screen :( My computer is nearly 5 years old I think if I can't fix it then I'll give it up.

Answer (score 2):

Have u tried booting into "Ubuntu recovery mode"?? Is that option visible on the log in screen?

Comment: I would go with TSJNachos117

Comment: No not visible.